# if block without else shell script in %preun scriptlet

Tags: bash, shell, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have the following script in my spec file %preun tag:

```
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then 
echo "Stopping blah service before uninstalling.." 
. /etc/init.d/blahforever stop 
echo "blah service stopped."
fi
```

I get "syntax error near unexpected token `fi'" error

but when I add else block it runs fine:

```
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Stopping blah service before uninstalling.." 
    . /etc/init.d/blahforever stop 
    echo "blah service stopped."
else
    echo "I dont need else block"
fi
```

But I don't need an else block! How do I get rid of it?
PS: I tried removing the semi colon after the condition and still didn't help.

Comment: That looks like it points to an error in /etc/init.d/blahforever

Comment: You also appear to have indented the script some in that change (and who knows what else). If you remove those two else/echo lines from the bottom snippet do you still get that syntax error? (Also why dot-source the service script invocation?)

Comment: Yes I did try removing all echo lines and still fails. And the script works as I said if I just remove the else block it will work.

Comment: @EtanReisner removing indentation seems to work!

Comment: What do you mean "removing indentation seems to work"? That doesn't make sense. Can you paste the **exact** lines in your scriptlet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell syntax error in the line ". /etc/init.d/blahforever stop".

There is no file to be sourced (i.e. read into the current shell)
called "stop".

Comment: No the script runs fine, as I said if I only add an else block, the whole script runs with no problems!

Comment: Yes "runs" while being sourced and then causes an error

Comment: Dot sourced files can be given arguments this way. The init script gets `stop` as `$1` with this call.

Comment: I defer to pedantry. ;-) Running as . sourced (rather than invoking directly) is certainly the unusual feature. Running the %post script with "sh -e -x test.sh" will exit on an error